# React doesn't update data for loops

Tags: arrays, reactjs, loops, react-hooks, react-state

I've this problem with React:

```js
<div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    {servers.database?.map((server, index) => (
                        <div className="col">

                            <div className="card" style={{ width: "18rem", backgroundColor: "#101114", color: "white", marginTop: "80px", borderRadius: "15px", boxShadow: "4px 3px 5px 0px #7335fb" }}>
                                <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/843104500713127946/a_91371d39bec9e454d0f4ccacbfaea9f8.gif?size=512" className="card-img-top" alt="Icona server" style={{ borderRadius: "50%", width: "96px", marginLeft: "20px", marginTop: "60px" }} />
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <h5 className="card-title">{servers.bot?[index].name || "Errore!"}</h5><br />
                                    <p className="card-text">{server.shortDescription}</p><br />
                                    <a href="#" className="btn" style={{ backgroundColor: "#5316d9", color: "white" }}>Entra</a>
                                    <a href="#" className="btn" style={{ marginLeft: "10px", backgroundColor: "#5316d9", color: "white" }}>Visita</a>
                                    <br />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

I have this code. 
Initially the `servers` is empty, so it doesn't load anything, and this is fine, but, when I update that object, I don't see any change in the page. 
This is the code that I use for update the object:

```js
    async function getServers() {

        console.log("ready")

        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/server/servers').then(res => res.json())

        setServers(response);

        console.log(servers);
    }
```

I'm sure that the object is updated with necessary data.

`useEffect` that run the function:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        getServers();
        import('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap');
        WebFont.load({
            google: {
                families: [ 'Karla:600', 'sans-serif' ]
            }
        });
    }, []);
```

How I can fix that? 
Thanks in advance and sorry for bad english.

Comment: `console.log(servers);` will show the old value not the new value. console.log response and show us what that is. My guess is it doesn't have a database key so nothing is mapped.

Comment: I know, but the problem is that it should show a card for every array element, but it doesn't work.
I'm sure that is an array, and watching the console, I can tell that log 2 times an empty object, but after it print the correct object.

Comment: @BlackdestinXX we already know it doesn't work. Can you show us the console.log result?

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be you are never calling `getServers`. You can do this by using the useEffect() hook. This will call the function once when the component is first rendered.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getServers()
}, []);
```

Comment: Doesn't work anyways

Answer (score 0):

the render function in React works faster than useEffect, so it will first render the page with

`servers = []`

and then it will update with 'setServers' - if that's a state variable it should work.

is it a state variable?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't update anything

Comment: in the line - ```{servers.database?.map((server, index) => (```

try changing it to - ```{servers && servers.database.map((server, index) => (```
so it will re-render everything servers is changed

Answer (score 0):

Here I have added an extra check for checking whether the **servers** is returning **undefined** or not

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [servers, setServers] = useState();

  const getServers = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then(res => res.json());

    setServers(response);

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getServers();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          {servers !== undefined &&
            servers.map((server, index) => (
              <div className="col" key={index}>
                <p>{server.title}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

you can also check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-glitter-dpox1?file=/src/App.js:0-717)

Comment: Doesn't work, no error or anything

Comment: Did you check your API response? have you got data from the API

Comment: yes, i receive all necessary data.